# OrientDB Java API dropIndex

Tags: java, orientdb

I've created property and index using the java api:

```
OrientVertexProperty orientVertexProperty = orientClass.createProperty(currentPropDef.getName(), currentPropertyType);

orientVertexProperty.createIndex(INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE);
```

But there is no drop or remove index method.
How can I drop the index using the JAVA API?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g.dropIndex("<class name>.<indexend property>");
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.